# Can jsoup auto detect xml encoding?

Tags: character-encoding, jsoup

Hi i have an xml file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
```

can jsoup auto detect the encoding of an xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it cannot. This is an open issue at the [Github/jsoup](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/221) and has been for ~2 years. As far as I know it is still the same.